# Spring batch meta data mannuvally creation in Job Respository

Tags: spring-batch

In mysql meta data manually creation time am getting this exception.
please suggest me any one.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1548)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:660)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at john.deere.com.MetaApp.main(MetaApp.java:13)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:56)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:171)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:135)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CompositeDatabasePopulator.populate(CompositeDatabasePopulator.java:56)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:47)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getReader(EncodedResource.java:132)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.readScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:228)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:168)
    ... 18 more
am traying to execute this..
In my applicationDb.xml is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
        <!-- connect to database -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MANU" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="****" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
 <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
  </jdbc:initialize-database>
</beans>
```

AND MY APPLICATION.XML IS

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
 <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
    </bean>
     <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="simpleJob" class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob" abstract="true">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you show how you have defined your data source bean? It seems that there is an issue with accessing the actual database.

Comment: try `classpath:/schema-drop-mysql.sql`; this is a spring resource access problem and not a SB error

Comment: please find my configuration